# where like - doctrine - symfony

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony1, doctrine

```
News:
id | title | sub
1  | one   | sub1
2  | two   | sub2


public function executeSearch(sfWebRequest $request)
{      
  $q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('News')
          ->createQuery('a')
          ->where("a.title LIKE %?%", array($request->getParameter('text')));

  if ($request->getParameter('sub')){
           $q->andWhere('a.subtile = sub2');
  }
  $test = $q->execute();
}
```

if i send title = one then show me ok, same as if title = two, but if i entered in input search "one two" then this not working. How change SQL query and code for this? I would like if i entered "one two", then show me title id 1 and title id 2. Now nothing show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to break the search query to words, and add them all to the doctrine query:

```
foreach(explode(" ", $request->getParameter("title")) as $v) {
  $q->orWhere("a.title LIKE %?%", $v);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
foreach(explode(" ", $request->getParameter("title")) as $k => $v) {
   ->orWhere('u.email LIKE :keyword'.$k )
   ->setParameter('keyword'.$k, '%'.$v.'%');
}
```

That was the only way Doctrine has accepted parameters with `LIKE %`.